# Swift: unwrapped optionals in closure in AFNetworking call

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, afnetworking

When I call certain methods that contain GET requests using the AFHTTPRequestOperation Manager, it sometimes improperly calls back to another succeed block/closure from another GET request using the Operation Manager.

This is the 3rd line in the error log below:

```
partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@in (Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.AFHTTPRequestOperation>,  
Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject>)) -> (@out ()) to @callee_owned (@owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.AFHTTPRequestOperation>,  
@owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject>) -> (@unowned ()) (AppDelegate.swift:615)
```

And the 2nd line:

```
reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.AFHTTPRequestOperation>,  
@owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject>) -> (@unowned ()) to @callee_owned (@in (Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.AFHTTPRequestOperation>,  
Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject>)) -> (@out ()) with unmangled suffix "_constprop0" (GroupsDataSource.swift:365)
```

Here is the error log I get.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BREAKPOINT UNKNOWN at 0x0000000100147e48

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Kickit                         0x0000000100147e48 Kickit.GroupsDataSource.(logoutForce (Kickit.GroupsDataSource) -> () -> ()).(closure #1) (GroupsDataSource.swift:809)
1  Kickit                         0x00000001001474dc Kickit.GroupsDataSource.(logoutForce (Kickit.GroupsDataSource) -> () -> ()).(closure #1) (GroupsDataSource.swift:823)
2  Kickit                         0x0000000100143074 reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.AFHTTPRequestOperation>, @owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject>) -> (@unowned ()) to @callee_owned (@in (Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.AFHTTPRequestOperation>, Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject>)) -> (@out ()) with unmangled suffix "_constprop0" (GroupsDataSource.swift:365)
3  Kickit                         0x0000000100193934 partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@in (Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.AFHTTPRequestOperation>, Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject>)) -> (@out ()) to @callee_owned (@owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.AFHTTPRequestOperation>, @owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject>) -> (@unowned ()) (AppDelegate.swift:615)
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001970253ac _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019702536c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000197029980 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 932
7  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000186241fa4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
8  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018624004c __CFRunLoopRun + 1492
9  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018616d0a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
10 GraphicsServices               0x000000018f30f5a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
11 UIKit                          0x000000018aaa23c0 UIApplicationMain + 1488
12 Kickit                         0x0000000100193ca4 main (AppDelegate.swift:15)
13 libdyld.dylib                  0x000000019704ea08 start + 4
```

The success block here is AppDelegate: 615. GroupsDataSource: 365 and GroupsDataSource: 809 are similarly structured.

```
let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

var user_id : Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("user_id") as Int

if (justSeenEventIDs.count > 0){
    manager.GET(serverURL+"users/seen_events.json",
        parameters: ["user_id" : userID()!, "event_ids" : justSeenEventIDs],
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) -> Void in

            println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)
            if (responseObject.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)){


            }


        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
            println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription + " code: " + "\(error.code)")
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using Alamofire instead of AFNetworking and that ended up resolving my issue. Written by the creator of AFNetworking github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire